# How to format numbers as percentage values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Was using ExtJS for formatting numbers to percentage earlier. Now as we are not using ExtJS anymore same has to be accomplished using normal JavaScript.

Need a method that will take number and format (usually in %) and convert that number to that format.

```
0 -> 0.00% = 0.00%
25 -> 0.00% = 25.00%
50 -> 0.00% = 50.00%
150 -> 0.00% = 150.00%
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is what you need.

```js
var x=150;
console.log(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)+"%");
x=0;
console.log(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)+"%");
x=10
console.log(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)+"%");
```

Comment: Not all languages have % at the end, this is not "formatting"

Answer (score 95):

You can use [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
var num=25;
var s = Number(num/100).toLocaleString(undefined,{style: 'percent', minimumFractionDigits:2}); 
console.log(s);
```

No '%' sign needed, output is:

```
25.00%
```

See documentation for [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for more options for the format object parameter.

Comment: Don't forget to check browser compatibility for `toLocaleString` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

#### Modern JS:

For any of these, remove `* 100` if you start with a whole number instead of decimal.

**Basic**

```js
const displayPercent = (percent) => `${(percent * 100).toFixed(2)}%`;
```

**Dynamic with safe handling for undefined values**

```js
const displayPercent = (percent, fallback, digits = 2) =>
  (percent === null || percent === undefined) ? fallback : `${(percent * 100).toFixed(digits)}%`;
```

#### Typescript:

```
const displayPercent = (percent: number) => `${(percent * 100).toFixed(2)}%`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(num) {
number = num.toString();;
console.log(number)
var words2 = number.split(".");
    for (var i = 0; i < words2.length; i++) {
        words2[i] += " ";
    }

    num1 = words2[0];
    num2 = words2[1];

    num1 = num1.trim();

    if(num2==undefined){
         number1 = num1+'.00%';
         return number1;
    }else{
         num2 = num2.trim();
         number1 = num1+'.'+num2+'%';
         return number1;
    }

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(50.12);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had decimal values such as `0.01235` and `0.016858542` that I wanted to convert to percentages 1.235% and 1.6858542% respectively. I thought it was going to be easy, just calculate `(0.012858542 * 100)` and I'm good to go. I was wrong, `(0.012858542 * 100) = 1.2858542000000002` because of decimal conversion.

Let's add [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to the calculation and I end up with the right value.

```
(0.012858542*100).toFixed(7)    // returns "1.2858542"
(0.01235*100).toFixed(7)        // returns "1.2350000"
```

I don't like to show four trailing zeros when they're unnecessary. One solution I thought about was to use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove all trailing zeros but I ended up using [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) instead because it does all the work for me while it's lightweight. I can recommend it!

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

numeral(0.012858542 * 100).format('0.00[0000]') // returns "1.2858542"
numeral(0.01235 * 100).format('0.00[0000]')     // returns "1.235"
```

Answer (score -1):

Transform number to percentage with X float decimal positions

```
function toPercent(number, float) {
  var percent = parseFloat(number * 100).toFixed(float) + "%";
  return percent;
}
```