# bold tags don't take effect in span element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm totally new to html, css and javascript.

I'm trying to create a simple interest rate calculator and I want to style the result so that the numbers in the result message are highlighted like this:

> Interest : If you deposit **10**,
> at an interest rate of **10.25**.
> You will receive an amount of **11.025**,
> in the year **2023**.

What I get is the `<b>` elements rendered as text, for example:

> Interest : If you deposit <b>10</b>,
> at an interest rate of <b>10.25</b>.
> You will receive an amount of <b>11.025</b>,
> in the year <b>2023</b>.

My code is this:

```js
function compute()
{
    var principal = document.getElementById("principal").value;
    var rate      = document.getElementById("rate").value;
    var years     = document.getElementById("years").value;
    var interest  = principal * (rate / 100) * years;
    // add amount to principal
    let amount    = interest + parseInt(principal);
    var year      = new Date().getFullYear() + parseInt(years);

    var interestString = "If you deposit " + principal.bold() + ",\n at an interest rate of " + rate + ".\n You will receive an amount of " + amount + ",\n in the year " + year + ".";
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = interestString
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color:black;
    font-family: arial;
    color:white
}

h1 {
    color: grey;
    font-family: verdana
}

.maindiv {
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    width:300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
    Amount <input type="number"  id="principal">  
    <br/>
    Rate <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" value="10.25"  oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>10.25</output>   
    <br/>
    No. of Years 
    <select id="years">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Interest : <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

I would be happy for a way to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: You can reformat your code to make it a lot more readable, btw - such as aligning assignments by `=` and not writing self-closing HTML elements over multiple lines.

Comment: @Dai can you give me an example?

Comment: I've edited your question already.

Comment: FYI: the [bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) method is deprecated and probably shouldn't be used anymore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should put **innerHTML** instead of *innerText*

```js
function compute()
{
    var principal = document.getElementById("principal").value;
    var rate      = document.getElementById("rate").value;
    var years     = document.getElementById("years").value;
    var interest  = principal * (rate / 100) * years;
    // add amount to principal
    let amount    = interest + parseInt(principal);
    var year      = new Date().getFullYear() + parseInt(years);

    var interestString = "If you deposit " + principal.bold() + ",\n at an interest rate of " + rate + ".\n You will receive an amount of " + amount + ",\n in the year " + year + ".";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = interestString
}
```

```css
body {background-color:black;font-family:arial;color:white}
h1{color:grey;font-family: verdana}

.maindiv {
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    width:300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
    Amount <input type="number"  id="principal">  
    <br/>
    Rate <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" value="10.25"  oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
    <output>10.25</output>   
    <br/>
    No. of Years 
    <select id="years">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Interest : <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't correctly handle invalid form state: when I run your answer's code-snippet when the amount input is blank (not zero) the `principapl.bold()` text just doesn't appear and the final amount is shown as `NaN`. When the form is valid this answer doesn't render the other values as bold, as per the OP's posting.

Comment: Being critical of _actual_ technical problems with a posted answer is not "toxic": we're here to help and our feedback is intended as _constructive criticism_ - it is not a personal-attack nor is it any kind of _ad-hom_ response. I appreciate that we SO users are not very accommodating for beginners, but if you're going to be providing advice for other users in your answers then you need be sure your answer is correct and robust, which it is not.  SO answers are not meant to be read by _only_ the original question-asker, but remain as a resource for _everyone else_, hence why standards matter.

Comment: Any way, the asker and I benefited from this question! and I am positive the other guys would benefit!

Answer (score 2):

Change `innerText` to `innerHTML`.

Comment: This will work, but it isn't the safest approach (as inappropriate use of `innerHTML` is the leading cause of XSS vulnerabilities). Personally I'd just use `<output>` elements or `.textContent`, and CSS without any `<b>` elements.

Comment: Me too @Dai but that was not a question :)

Answer (score 1):

- [The `String.prototype.bold()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) (which wraps any JavaScript `string` value in a `<b>` element) is deprecated and should not be used - unless you suddenly found yourself time-warped back to 1995.
- Instead, I recommend making your "template" into normal HTML, and use `<output>` elements as placeholders, and use CSS to make all `<output>` elements bold.

Something like this:

- My code uses `Intl.NumberFormat` to [format monetary-amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings) [and percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163256/how-to-format-numbers-as-percentage-values-in-javascript) appropriately

  - When formatting percentages, remember that `number` percentage values have to be normalized to `0-1.0`; so `10%` is `0.1` and `250%` is `2.5`, and `1.25%` is `0.0125`.
- Because JavaScript doesn't have compile-time (or parse-time) type-checking, my code employs *defensive-programming* techniques to preemptively fast-fail if anything goes wrong by doing `throw new Error`, including:

  - Verifying that HTML elements referenced by `getElementById` or `querySelector` actually exist (with `function getElement`).
  - Precondition validation that verifies parameter argument value types and other value *things* (e.g. numeric range bounds-checking).
  - JSDoc (`/** @param */`, etc) is used [to document parameter types in a machine-readable format](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html).
- I cleaned-up the HTML and wrapped related form fields in `<div class="field">`) and added a currency-symbol to the `<input id="principal" />` field.

```js
const fmtUsd  = new Intl.NumberFormat( 'en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' } );
const fmtPerc = new Intl.NumberFormat( 'en-US', { style: 'percent', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 } );

function compute( e ) {

  const errorOutput     = getElement( 'errorOutput'    , 'div' );
  const outputContainer = getElement( 'outputContainer', 'div' );
  
  try {
    
    const principalInput = getElement( 'principal', 'input[type="number"]' );
    const rateInput      = getElement( 'rate'     , 'input[type="range"]' );
    const yearsSelect    = getElement( 'years'    , 'select' );
    
    const principalAmount = getNumberValue( principalInput );
    const ratePercDbl     = getNumberValue( rateInput ) / 100.0;
    const yearsCount      = getNumberValue( yearsSelect );
    
    computeInner( principalAmount, ratePercDbl, yearsCount );
    
    // No errors, so show the output div and hide any previous error messages:
    outputContainer.hidden = false;
    errorOutput    .hidden = true;
  }
  catch( err ) {
    // Something went wrong! So hide the normal output <div> and show the error details:
    errorOutput.hidden = false;
    errorOutput.textContent = ( err || "(Unknown error)" ).toString() + "\r\n\r\n" + ( err.stack );
    outputContainer.hidden = true;
  }
}

/**
 * @param {number} principalAmount
 * @param {number} interestRatePerc
 * @param {number} yearsCount
 */
function computeInner( principalAmount, interestRatePerc, yearsCount ) {

  // Preconditions:
  if( typeof principalAmount != 'number' ) throw new Error( "Expected `principalAmount` to be `number` but encountered " + typeof principalAmount );
  if( typeof interestRatePerc != 'number' ) throw new Error( "Expected `interestRatePerc` to be `number` but encountered " + typeof interestRatePerc );
  if( typeof yearsCount != 'number' || yearsCount <= 0 ) throw new Error( "Expected `yearsCount` to be a positive `number` but encountered " + ( typeof yearsCount ) + " \"" + yearsCount.toString() + "\" instead." );
  
  //
  
  const interest    = principalAmount * interestRatePerc * yearsCount;
  const totalAmount = interest + principalAmount;
  const endYear     = new Date().getFullYear() + yearsCount;
  
  //
  
  setOutput( 'principal', principalAmount , fmtUsd  );
  setOutput( 'rate'     , interestRatePerc, fmtPerc );
  setOutput( 'years'    , endYear                   );
  
  const amountOut = getElement( 'receiveAmountOut', 'output' );
  amountOut.value = fmtUsd.format( totalAmount );
}

/**
 * @param {string} outputFor
 * @param {number} value
 * @param {Intl.NumberFormat} formatter
 */
function setOutput( outputFor, value, formatter ) {
   
  const formattedValue = formatter ? ( formatter.format( value ) ) : ( value.toString() );
   
  const selector = 'output[for~="' + CSS.escape( outputFor ) +'"]';
  const outputs  = document.querySelectorAll( selector );
  for( const outputEl of outputs ) {
    outputEl.value = formattedValue;
  }
}

/**
 * @param {string} id
 * @param {string} validationSelector
 * @returns {HTMLElement}
 */
function getElement( id, validationSelector ) {
  const el = document.getElementById( id );
  if( el === null ) throw new Error( "No element with `id=\"" + id + "\"` was found." );
  if( !el.matches( validationSelector ) ) throw new Error( "The element with `id=\"" + id + "\"` does not match selector \"" + validationSelector + "\"." );
   
  return el;
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement} input
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getNumberValue( input ) {
   
  // Preconditions:
  if( !( input instanceof HTMLElement ) ) throw new Error( 'Expected `input` to be a HTML element.' );
  if( !( input.tagName === 'SELECT' || input.tagName === 'INPUT' ) ) throw new Error( 'Expected `input` to be a HTML <input /> or <select> element.' );
   
   //
   
  let valueNumber;
  if( input.tagName === 'SELECT' ) {
     valueNumber = parseInt( input.value, /*radix:*/ 10 );
  }
  else if( input.type === 'number' ) { // Can't use valueAsNumber with type="range", grr.
     valueNumber = input.valueAsNumber;
  }
  else {
     valueNumber = parseFloat( input.value );
  }
   
  if( isNaN( valueNumber ) ) {
    throw new Error( "Form <input> or <select> has invalid value: \"" + input.value + "\"." );
   }
   
   return valueNumber;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white
}
.maindiv {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}

h1 {
    color: grey;
    font-family: verdana
}

.field {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
  .field > label,
  .field > input,
  .field > div > input {
    display: block;
  }

#principalField.field > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
  #principalField.field > div > span.symbol {
    display: inline-block;
    
    /* Width is 1em with negative right margin of -1.5em to make the currency symbol appear "inside" the <input />. Also, identical font-size, padding and border as Chrome's default style for <input />: */
    width: 1em;
    margin: 0 -1.5em 0 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    z-index: 10;
    
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 90%;
  }


#errorOutput {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 7px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

output {
  font-weight: bold;
}
output:empty {
  display: none;
}

input[type="number"] {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">

    <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
    
    <div class="field" id="principalField">
      <label for="principal">Principal amount</label>
      <div>
        <span class="symbol">$</span>
        <input type="number" id="principal" oninput="compute(event)" value="123.00" size="6" />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="field">
      <label for="rate">Interest rate (<output for="rate">10.25%</output>)</label>
      <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" value="10.25" oninput="compute(event)" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="field">
      <label for="years">No. of Years </label>
      <select id="years" oninput="compute(event)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <button hidden type="button" onclick="compute(event)">Compute Interest</button>
    
    <div id="outputContainer" hidden>
    
        If you deposit <output for="principal"></output>
        at an interest rate of <output for="rate"></output>
        you will receive an amount of <output id="receiveAmountOut"></output> in the year <output for="years"></output>.
    
    </div>
    <div id="errorOutput" hidden></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interestString to this

```
  var interestString = `If you deposit  <b>${principal}</b>,<br>
  at aninterest rate of <b>${rate}</b>.<br>
  You will receive an amount of <b>${amount}</b>,<br>
  in the year <b>${year}</b>.`;
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=interestString
```

and use innerHTML instead of innerText and it will look exactly like the example you gave above!